# How do i get Owl carousel to work in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, carousel, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel Div in my Laravel project that won't load. I need your help in finding out why this is happening.

1. I have tried importing the latest cdn js and css for owl,
2. I have loaded the scripts file involved in the same blade that has the carousel but same results

This image shows how it loads in a Laravel blade

[image]

Here is an image of how it loads in Html

[image: Here is an image of how it's supposed to load]

`testimonials.blade.php`

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="sec-title clrwhite text-center">
                <p>Testimonials</p>
                <div class="title">Words From Customers</div>
                <div class="border-box center"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="testimonial-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/1.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Shelly Johnson</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>California</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/2.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Cathrine Wagner</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>Los Angeles</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                        
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/1.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Shelly Johnson</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>California</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/2.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Cathrine Wagner</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>Los Angeles</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                        
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/1.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Shelly Johnson</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>California</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <!--Start Single Testimonial Item-->
                        <div class="single-testimonial-item text-center">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <img src="images/testimonial/2.png" alt="Awesome Image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-content">
                                <div class="text-box">
                                    <p>Your guys were knowledgeable, experienced, efficient and neat. A true to work with Uniafric.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="client-info">
                                    <h3>Cathrine Wagner</h3>
                                    <p><span class="icon-point"></span>Los Angeles</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <!--End Single Testimonial Item-->
                       
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="button text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                <a class="btn-three" href="#">Read More Words<span class="icon-null"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @section('scripts')
        <script src="{{asset('front/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- <script src="{{asset('front/js/owl.js')}}"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
@endsection
```

`app.blade.php`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    
        <!-- responsive meta -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- For IE -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css')}}">
        
        <!-- master stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('front/css/style.css')}}">
        <!-- Responsive stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('front/css/responsive.css')}}">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-57x57.png')}}">
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"> -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-60x60.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-72x72.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-76x76.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-114x114.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-120x120.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-144x144.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-152x152.png')}}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/apple-icon-180x180.png')}}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/android-icon-192x192.png')}}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/favicon-32x32.png')}}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/favicon-96x96.png')}}">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/favicon-16x16.png')}}">
        <link rel="manifest" href="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/manifest.json')}}">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="{{asset('front/images/favicon-one/ms-icon-144x144.png')}}">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
       
    @include('includes.header')
    @include('includes.nav')
    <!-- END nav -->
    
    {{--Start Content--}}
    @yield('content')
    {{--End Content--}}
    
    @include('includes.footer')
     
    </head>
    <!-- GetButton.io widget -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var options = {
                whatsapp: "+254727529830", // WhatsApp number
                call_to_action: "We are online", // Call to action
                position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
                pre_filled_message: "Hello, how may we help you? Just send us a message", // WhatsApp pre-filled message
            };
            var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "getbutton.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
            var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
            s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
        })();
    </script>
    <!-- /GetButton.io widget -->
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/wow.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.fancybox.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.countTo.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/appear.js')}}"></script>
    
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/validation.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.mixitup.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/isotope.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.paroller.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/jquery.enllax.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB2uu6KHbLc_y7fyAVA4dpqSVM4w9ZnnUw"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/gmaps.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/map-helper.js')}}"></script>
    
    <script src="{{asset('front/assets/language-switcher/jquery.polyglot.language.switcher.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/assets/timepicker/timePicker.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/bootstrap-select.min.js')}}"></script>                          
    <script src="{{asset('front/assets/html5lightbox/html5lightbox.js')}}"></script>
    
    <!--Revolution Slider-->
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js')}}"></script>
    
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('front/js/main-slider-script.js')}}"></script>
    
    <!-- thm custom script -->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    @yield('scripts')
```

Comment: is there any error in the console of developer tools (press F12 then select Console then reload the page)

Comment: That's the most confusing part, there is no error pointing to the owl carousel.                    Here is a screenshot of the errors I am getting. https://ibb.co/7tsYxTT kindly check

Comment: then could you compare the html result of the blade file with your html version and see if there are differences

Comment: This is the error logs on the console for HTML kindly check https://ibb.co/LxZk1ty